# Smoothing Movement In Lower-Level Networking for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

So I'm in the process of writing a networked game for Unity and we have to work with the lower level network API for Unity. In other words, we can only use NetworkServer, NetworkClient, and NetworkIdentity.

Forbidden ones are NetworkTransform and NetworkManager.

So we have all of our networking up and running. Everything is working fine. Basic overview of how our networking for movement is...

1. Client presses key and sends input to move
2. Packet is created and sent under the Opcode.MOVEMENT
3. Server receives and processes movement. We have no mitigation (we had bucket synchronization but disabled it because it was giving issues). In the update method we continuously send the position of all the players out to each other.
4. All clients continuously receive positions of other players and update it accordingly.

**Observed effects**: On the server side things are pristine. Movement is extremely smooth. On the client end there is a noticeable framerate loss. Things aren't super smooth, but the player moves without jitter. Overall: no jitter, but not smooth either.

What would be the best way to smoothing out movement on clients?

Comment: `Vector3.Lerp`...You will need that a lot when moving objects in network games.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks! I'm trying to work with it right now and I noticed a lot of people have been using time to set their float t. I'm not sure what's the best or how people came up with these calculations. What would you recommend for just straight input and movement in interpolation? I'm assuming I lerp on the Client side, and leave the server side alone?

Comment: Note that the network movement and smooth stuff is really complicated. I said complicated because you still need to predict the movement in order to get better result but to answer your question, `Time.deltaTime * yourSpeed` variable should be fine for the `t` in `Vector3.Lerp`.

Comment: You lerp on both sides. If you are on the server, you lerp the client movement. If you are the client, you lerp the server movement.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks a lot for your information. It really helps. The issue now is that my movement speed on the player is only like .05 so lerping with .05 * Time.deltaTime is extremely slow.

Edit: Ignore that since we were using that original speed for transform.position lol

Comment: `yourSpeed` which is your multiplier should be a `public` variable you can modify from the Editor. You have to change that during run-time to see which value works best for you instead of just using `.05`. I found the easy network article about movement objects in a network game  and think you should read it. [Here](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/fast_paced_multiplayer.html) is the link.

Comment: @Programmer I'll give that a look. At the moment we ran into an issue after lerping server and client end. The server end moves a lot faster than the client, which is much much slower (but smooth now). Gonna give it a few runs.

Comment: @Programmer I am curious though. On a local area network where I'm just sending packets to Server to process movement, which sends the actual position back to client so they can adjust: why does it seem so laggy even on a LAN?

Comment: It shouldn't lag in your local network. Maybe there are many people on your network or your network is slow. If you are sure that your code is correct but it is still lagging then I suggest you go with raw TCP/UDP socket instead of Unity's network API. I think you should test that and see the performance difference.